# what does kernel and cokernel really mean in some theorems？

Tags: abstract-algebra

Recently I am studying aluffi's algebra chapter 0.And when I came across kernel and cokernel in some theorem like snake lemma or “having left （right）inverse is equivalent to split monomorphism（epimorphism）”theorem,which are in $R-Mod$.I got lost .I understand the kernel and coker in two ways.

1. “standard”definition（say.$coker＝N/imφ$）
2. the definition in terms of universal property which is not unique though “unique up to isomorphism”

so in these theorem （or more that I dont come across）.what does ker and coker really mean?

if they mean standard definition，I find that the proofs of these theorem more easy,because such definition are more concrete.  while the only thing I could use about the other definition is their universal property,with which the proof could be done but harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of universal properties is that it doesn't matter. Either view is correct, though I strongly recommend getting comfortable with proving things solely from their universal properties.

If you have shown that your concrete definition satisfies the universal property then: if the use of $ker$ is stated to be mean something which satisfies the universal property, then, using those "unique isomorphisms", you can translate those instances to your concrete example, and proceed (and translate back along the isomorphisms at the end if necessary). (There's a subtlety here that whatever you're asking *respects* these isomorphisms. This is known as the [principle of equivalence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) in category theory, but with typical presentations it is not *a priori* true. That said, violations of it tend to correspond to "silly" questions along the lines of "Is $7\in\pi$?" so mathematicians largely behave as if it *does* hold a priori and just "understand" which questions are "silly" or not.)

Of course, if you prove the statement for anything which satisfies the universal property, then it will certainly hold for your concrete case too. So, in spirit, this is the view taken. Just like when you prove something about the integers, $\mathbb{Z}$, you usually don't bother stating which exact definition of the integers you have in mind. Your proof is likely in terms of properties that hold for any valid implementation of the integers.

There are several benefits to proving things in terms of universal properties. First, it's more general. Kernels and cokernels occur in a variety of categories. A proof of a property of (co)kernels will typically automatically apply to (co)kernels in any other category. Second, it's often more enlightening. There's a strong case to make that universal properties capture "the essence" of the constructions, e.g. the "essence" of what a kernel is. This is more transferable both between categories and within the category. For any particular (co)kernel, there may be a simpler and more direct way of demonstrating that it satisfies the universal property than expressing it as quotient. In fact (relating to the "principle of equivalence" remarks), you would technically have to say some module is *not* a (co)kernel unless it is explicitly *equal* to a quotient. Third, it can often *simplify* proofs. In general, generalizing can simplify proofs because it removes irrelevant detail and limits the approaches available to proof. This means that you're less likely to spend time exploring fruitless dead ends. Of course, the downside of this is that you have to think more abstractly, and you lose approaches that might significantly simplify the problem in the specific concrete case.

From a programming perspective, a universal property is like an interface for an abstract data type while an explicit construction is like an implementation of the interface. A proof with respect to a construction is like depending on implementation details. You can't transfer the proof to other implementations of the interface, and it might break if you make small changes to your implementation. In math-speak, you lose some naturality properties that you have to manually establish after the fact, and if you redefine (co)kernel via some other construction, even slightly, your proofs may no longer be valid. Mathematicians have largely been shielded from this because they work informally and so tweaks and variations of definitions are just glossed over. If mathematicians were using (mechanized) proof assistants, they'd be highly motivated to operate in terms of interfaces/universal properties, because they would not be able to gloss over these differences.

Comment: thank you very much!  I will try to think them from their universal properties.

Comment: but...I feel I'm cheating when I prove the general theorem by proving concrete example and translate it to any things satisfying universal property through the unique isomorphism...

Comment: You technically *are* cheating if you don't also prove that the property you're proving is invariant with respect to isomorphism. Another consequence mathematicians would face if they routinely used proof assistants is the failure of the principle of equivalence in standard foundations, though they could use other foundations, in particular [Homotopy Type Theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/), where the principle of equivalence *is* true, but this has some other costs.

Comment: The "silly" questions I referred to in my answer are properties that *aren't* invariant with respect to isomorphism (or sometimes more general notions of equivalence). Often these "silly" questions are "unnatural" in some intuitive sense, like the example I gave, but it's quite possible that a property isn't so obviously "silly", and it may take some experience to have a feel for a question's "silliness". A benefit of proving things in terms of universal properties is that it automatically means the property is isomorphism invariant.

Comment: So...should I always regard ker and coker as somthing satisfying the universal property,although the author mean concrete examples?（I find the author doesnt explain whether the symbol mean concrete example or not...）

Comment: I mean is way of thinking  always right？I dont konw whether there are some theorems which are right only in special concrete examples..

Comment: The author not specifying the specific construction used forces you to make your proof work for any construction, which is to say you are forced to work in terms of the universal property. You don't even need to *have* a construction, which enables hypothetical arguments. If you want to be safe, just always work in terms of universal properties if you aren't explicitly asked to prove something about a given construction. Your concerns are valid, but the cheating is widespread: the trick is learning when you can get away with it. It's definitely cleaner not to cheat in the first place, though.

Comment: oh,I find I still have some me questions.The first question is that I think in some situations I couldnt prove something without touching the concrete constrctions,for example,in group category,we have a group morphism φ:G→H, if we define the ker by the universal properties,I want to prove the morphism from kerφ to G is injective

Comment: I have no idea but get the concrete ker（denoted K）,and prove the inclusion from K toG is injective,then use the fact that the inclusion factors through the kerφ uniquely to complete the proof.Could the proof could be done without touching the concrete construction?I also have a question...may I write another comment..

Comment: another question.we want to prove the fact that in group category,kerφ is trivial ⇔φ is injective.If we use the fact that isomorphic group have the same order,then a kerφ is trivial⇒K is trivial⇒φ injective（where K also denote the concrete construction）. the converse is the same.So,in this examples I find things easy when we know a concrete construction .DOES it mean that the concrete construction help us detect the category？

Comment: I recommend attempting to prove these things on your own, then searching math.stackexchange and the internet in general for existing answers, and finally asking new questions if you can't prove it or find answers. It's easy to prove for equalizers are monomorphisms in general (in any category), and thus so are kernels. That monos are injective in $\mathbf{Grp} is a statement about the explicit definition of the arrows of $\mathbf{Grp}$ (or slightly more cleanly, the image of a forgetful functor from $\mathbf{Grp}$ to $\mathbf{Set}) and doesn't involve universal properties.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel (of $f$) in a general category is the fibered product (if it exists) $X\times_{Y} 0$ where $0$ is the terminal/initial object and the "fibered product" construction is mentioned in the beginning of the book (not this precise construction though). To be explicit, the diagram you should think of is
$$
0\to Y\overset{f}{\leftarrow}X
$$
The cokernel, as with most co-objects, is defined by flipping the arrows, so the fibered coproduct of the diagram
$$
0\leftarrow X\overset{f}{\to}Y
$$
Universality is something that can be said if we want to apply some general statement in a general category, but for your purposes, you can explicitly construct the fibered co-product and fibered product in the category of $R$-modules, which is precisely the definitions you obtained.

Comment: thanks,but I think if we use the definition in terms of universal property,these theorem are also true.But to prove it,is it sufficient that we only prove the standard -definition -version？

Comment: The proof of any theorem using the standard definition does not imply the theorem is true using the universal property. If the universal property coincides with the "standard definition" (which is generally obtained from the universal property), then yes. In general, the snake lemma is true in every abelian category (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category) since short exact sequences and the objects mentioned in my post _in fact_ exist.